# Spring servlets and async support in Grails 2.4.4

Tags: tomcat, grails, spring-websocket

Java 7, Tomcat 7, Grails 2.4.4

Using spring-websocket. When my browser hits the xhr_streaming or xhr endpoints (fallback options), I see this exception in the logs:

```
[ERROR] [2015-01-16 12:53:26,659]  [ajp-apr-10.11.64.209-8009-exec-41] o.c.g.g.w.e.GrailsExceptionResolver: IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [POST] /life/stomp/900/qkl3z58m/xhr_streaming
Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container. Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=<removed>/stomp/900/qkl3z58m/xhr_streaming; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure for request <removed>/stomp/900/qkl3z58m/xhr_streaming; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container**
```

According to WEB-INF/web.xml, I am on version 3.0, and my dispatcherServlet and all filters have async-enabled true (due to grails.servlet.version = "3.0" in BuildConfig.groovy).

Could there be something else going on with this error?

Comment: Have you tried adding the following to your `BuildConfig.groovy`? `grails.tomcat.nio = true` and `grails.tomcat.scan.enabled = true`